# How do I do a 301 redirect of specific pages with a catchall for any pages not specified?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

We are changing domains and need to redirect old pages to new, and then create a catch-all to redirect any that we missed.

This needs to be done as a 301 redirect using `.htaccess`.

For example:

1. Redirect `http://www.olddomain.com/page1` to `https://www.newdomain.com/page1`.
2. Redirect page2 the same way.
3. Redirect all other pages on `oldomain.com` to the home page of the new domain.

Answer (score 2):

You basically just need to perform the redirects in the order you've stated: 1, 2 and 3.

Assuming `newdomain.com` and `olddomain.com` point to different servers then you can use mod_alias:

```
Redirect 302 /page1 https://www.newdomain.com/page1
Redirect 302 /page2 https://www.newdomain.com/page2

# Redirect everything else to the home page
RedirectMatch 302 ^ https://www.newdomain.com/
```

However, redirecting to the home page is rarely a good user experience (and Google likely treats it as a soft-404 anyway). You could simply redirect `/<other-url>` to `newdomain.com/<other-url>` and allow the new site to handle it as a meaningful 404 - generally a better experience for users.

Note that `Redirect` is prefix-matching. Everything after the matched URL (eg. `/page1`) is appended onto the end of the target URL. If the old and new URLs are the same then you only need a single `Redirect` directive to redirect everything:

```
Redirect 302 / https://www.newdomain.com/
```

Note that these are obviously 302 (temporary) redirects. Change to a 301 (permanent) redirect only when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so you don't want incorrect redirects cached by the client.

---

If `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` are physically hosted on the same filesystem then you'll need to use mod_rewrite instead since you'll need to check the *host* header for the domain being accessed. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1$ https://www.newdomain.com/page1 [R=302,L]
```

Obviously, it would be far more efficient if `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` point to different places.

Comment: Thank you. And yeah, I like your idea on not redirecting everything to the home page. If there are a lot of hits on those we can deal with them individually. What would be the best way of redirecting to the same URL on the new domain for anything not specified directly?

Comment: Include the same directive as above (ie. `Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com/`) at the end of the other redirects. (Instead of the `RedirectMatch` directive.)

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)